# Site can't be reached when running IIS in Docker

Tags: windows, docker, iis

I followed the instructions on the official Dockerhub repo for IIS (https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis), but running into `"Site can't be reached"` when trying to access via the IP of the container.

I get `403 forbidden` when I try htp://localhost:8000.
I copied a `test.html` page into `C:/inetpub/wwwroot` and verified by logging into the container as well.

The results of appcmd list site is as follows:

SITE "Default Web Site" (id:1,bindings:http/*:80:,state:Started)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe Run `appcmd list site` first and paste its output as part of your question.

Comment: Hi Lex; i updated the question with the output of appcmd list site.

Comment: I was able to access the helloworld.html that I had placed in the C:/inetpub/wwwroot folder by directly accessing it at http://localhost:8000/helloworld.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 typically indicates that the web address we are trying to access is not the root directory of the website.
I doubt if there exist any files, which have been copied to the remote docker container.
Please make sure that the directory where the `dockerfile` is located contains the content folder and contains all site files.

```
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY content/ .
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your analysis. What i didn't realize is IIS perhaps serves index.html as default and my file was called helloworld.html which obviously wasn't going to be to served when i access localhost:8000; it works when i try localhost:8000/helloworld.html.